# Is there a way to order imported files before they are brought into a loop?

Tags: python, loops, file-conversion, img2pdf

I am attempting to convert all .job files in a folder into a single pdf. this code does that however they are in no particular order. I would like them to be imported in the order of the time the file was created or their filename it follows a set pattern 'XXX_1.jpg'

This is what I have so far:

```
import img2pdf
os.chdir('C:/Path')
# convert all files ending in .jpg inside a directory

with open("output.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert([i for i in os.listdir('.') if i.endswith(".jpg")]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can use `glob` to gather all the paths of the `files` in your directory into a list. Then with `os` module `getctime`, you can get the list of time of creation. I zipped both list, then made a dictionary whose keys are the file path and values - time of creation. Finally i got the dictionary arrange by values using the operator module to arrange all dictionary in descending order of values(i.e newest file first)

```
import os
import glob
import operator
import img2pdf

a= glob.glob("my_directory/*.jpg")
b = [os.path.getctime(i) for i in a]
c = {}
for i,j  in list(zip(a,b)):
    c[i] = j
sorted_c = dict(sorted(c.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True))
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert([k for k in sorted_c]))
```

Comment: Sidenote for subsequent readers : `getctime` can actually yield different behaviors depending on the OS you're using: 
- Windows, it'll give you the ***creation time*** for each file
- Unix Systems: It'll give you the ***time of the last metadata change*** for each file.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not mistaken, `os.listdir` returns a name-sorted list by default. If you want to sort them by last modification time, you can sort them using `os.getmtime` as a key:

```py
#import img2pdf
#import os

os.chdir('C:/Path')
paths = sorted(os.listdir('.'), key=os.path.getmtime)

with open("output.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert([i for i in paths if i.endswith(".jpg")]))
```

See the documentation for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

> os.path.getmtime(path)
>
> - Return the time of last modification of path. The return value is a floating point number giving the number of seconds since the epoch (see the time module). Raise OSError if the file does not exist or is inaccessible.